# HTML viewport meta tag became mandatory

Tags: html

Recently, I just discovered that I have to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to my HTML web pages now in order to render responsively on a phone or a tablet screen.

It wasn't the case last year where I didn't have that meta tag, and the page still worked responsively on a phone or a tablet screen.

Did HTML introduce a change that mandates that meta tag? Where do I see that changelog? And what change broke the responsiveness of the pages without the meta tag?

Comment: Consider whether you've changed anything on your end. Are you using a different browser? Different mobile device? Is it possible you were previously using Bootstrap or another library that effectively does the `meta` viewport thing for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It has been required to stop mobile devices from assuming websites were designed for desktop devices and zooming out since Apple introduced it with the original iPhone.